# Unexpected error While adding string in print() functuon

Tags: python-3.6

I have a simple function **fact()** to print factorial of a number which is to input at runtime.
Everything works fine ata this code given below.

```
# Find factorial of a number...

def fact():
    number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    tmp = 1
    while number > 0:
        tmp *= number
        number -= 1
    print(tmp)
    ask = input('Do you want to try again... [y/n]: ')
    if ('y' or 'Y') in ask:
        fact()
    else:
    print('Thank you for using my tool. Good bye')

fact()
```

But if I add some string in **first print() function** I get syntax error for the line "ask = input...". Here is the code below.

```
# Find factorial of a number...

def fact():
    number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    tmp = 1
    while number > 0:
        tmp *= number
        number -= 1
    print("Factorial of %d is %d" %(number, tmp)
    ask = input('Do you want to try again... [y/n]: ')
    if ('y' or 'Y') in ask:
        fact()
    else:
        print('Thank you for using my tool. Good bye')

fact()
```

I have one last problem. My program asks me if I want to try again. If I type y and enter, in works as it should be. But if I type Y, it exicute *else* statement.

I am using python3.6.4rc1 in Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work!

```
def fact():
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    tmp = 1
    while number > 0:
        tmp *= number
        number -= 1
    print("Factorial of %d is %d" %(number, tmp))
    ask = input("Do you want to try again... [y/n]: ")
    if ask in ['y','Y']:
        fact()
    else:
        print('Thank you for using my tool. Good bye')


fact()
```

Comment: @Pusko Your code is not working. ''Error in line 2. Expected an indention.''

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. Now it is working. I had a another problem in my code. I have fixed that. I had to preserve value of `number` as it will become 0 at end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had to preserve value of *number* variable as it will become 0 at end of loop. Otherwise my program will print *Modulas of 0 is 'some_number*. Now I have the correct code...

```
def fact(): 
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    preserve_number = number
    tmp = 1 
    while number > 0: 
        tmp *= number 
        number -= 1 
    print("Factorial of %d is %d" %(preserve_number, tmp)) 
    ask = input("Do you want to try again... [y/n]: ") 
    if ask in ['y','Y']: 
        fact() 
    else: 
        print('Thank you for using my tool. Good bye') 
fact()
```